# How do you index incomplete strings to JSON keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I would like to be able to type in "Hammerhead" to call the "Hammerhead Shark" object without its full name. Is this possible and if so how?

I tried using `array.indexOf(string)` though it doesn't really seem to help since it requires an exact match such as typing "Hammerhead Shark"

JS:

```
const JSON = require('animals.json');
var animals = Object.keys(JSON);

if (animals.indexOf("Hammerhead")) {
console.log(JSON["Hammerhead"].name);
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Hammerhead Shark": {
  "name": "Shark",
  "age": "300"
  },
  "Duck": {
  "name": "Duck",
  "age": "1000"
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be "Shark" instead of undefined.

Comment: You need to loop through the array, then you can check each one for the key you want.  You can't access the object directly with a string that doesn't match.

Comment: That `JSON` [isn't actually JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) - it's a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: Adding to @jmargolisvt comment, your if should have check for 0 or greater index as if that is the first key, it will return 0, which is falsey in JS

Comment: first let's clarify one thing, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), so what does your `const JSON` contain? json or an Object? Second: *"I would like to be able to type in "Hammerhead" to call the "Hammerhead Shark""* where do you want to type that? In your IDE? Are you talking about Intelligent code completion in your IDE? Or are we talking like autocompletition+fuzzy search for a form field in your Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to get access the value in object. By its partial name.

- Get the entries of object using `Object.entries()`
- Find the key which `includes()` the given partial key.
- return the second element of the found entry.

```js
const obj = { "Hammerhead Shark": { "name": "Shark", "age": "300" }, "Duck": { "name": "Duck", "age": "1000" } }

function getValueByPartialKey(obj,key){
  return (Object.entries(obj).find(([k,v]) => k.includes(key)) || [])[1]
}

console.log(getValueByPartialKey(obj,"Hammerhead"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.includes(word)` to return the name that matches the string that you're searching for, along with `Array.filter` iterates over the values too, and returns the result(s) you want.